# How to render django-cms plugin in every page?

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a latest news plugin for django-cms.

I want to show 5 latest news in footer. Footer placed on every page of site.

How can I render this plugin on every page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are some template tags that should help you achieve what you are trying to do:

```
{% placeholder "footer" inherit %}
```

should inherit its content from pages above in the hierarchy, or you can render a place holder from another page with

```
{% show_placeholder "footer" "home" %}
```

you can also make a combination like

```
   {% placeholder "footer" or %}
   {% show_placeholder "footer" "home" %}
   {% endplaceholder %}
```

which will normally render the contents of the placeholder "footer" from page "home", but if you place something in the placeholder of the current page it will render this content!

Comment: Yes a choice that makes also sense!

Comment: This is--surprisingly--the only thing I've tried that works. And I have seen other solutions that look like they should work, but don't. Thank you so much.

Comment: Side note: you have to give your page an ID under Advanced Settings. For example, I gave my home page the id "homepage" and use that instead of "home".