# Django-CMS show_placeholder not working as expected

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm working on a site where the footer content is shared across all pages. What is the best way to do in Django-CMS?

I tried using show_placeholder tag, but it somehow didn't work. A little more details on what I did:

First, I have a {% placeholder footer_info %} in base.html. Then I add a page called "Home" (template homepage.html) in django admin and put some text under footer_info as a Text plugin. As the accepted answer in this question suggested (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616745/how-to-render-django-cms-plugin-in-every-page),

I add

```
{% placeholder footer_info or %}
{% show_placeholder footer_info "Home" %}
{% endplaceholder %}
```

In a template called services.html which I used as the template for page Services.
However, the content in home page is not showing up in services page. I also tried adding an id home_cms_page to home page in the Advanced option area, so that I can reference it in services.html like this:

```
{% placeholder footer_info or %}
{% show_placeholder footer_info "home_cms_page" %}
{% endplaceholder %}
```

But the content is still not showing up.

Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? And is this the best way of getting some content from a page across all other pages (and I have to add show_placeholder in every other page)?

Thank you

---

**EDIT:**

It is not a multilingual site. I commented out `'cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware',` because the only language I use on the site is English.

I have this in my base.html:

```
{% load cms_tags sekizai_tags %}

<!-- all the rest of the HTML markups -->

<div class="span4">

{% placeholder footer_info %}

</div>
```

Then I added a page in the admin called "Home" with a Text plugin and an id of "home_cms_page".

The following is in my services.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load cms_tags %}

{% block base_content %}
    {% placeholder services_info %}
{% endblock base_content %}

{% block page_content %}
<a href="{% page_url "home_cms_page" %}">Home page</a>
{% endblock page_content %}

{% placeholder "footer_info" or %}
{% show_placeholder "footer_info" "home_cms_page" %}
{% endplaceholder %}
```

Comment: Did you try `{% show_placeholder "footer_info" "home_cms_page" %}` (with quotes)?

Comment: Yes, I tried almost everything I can think of. With quotes, without quotes, with template name, with page-id, there's still no contents from home showing up on services page. Is my setup incorrect in any way? I put the placeholder footer_info in base.html (without quotes, I think quotes don't really matter based on my experiments), add some contents to the footer_info placeholder in home_cms_page from the admin area, then in the template for services I put in the snippet above.

Comment: Is thisa multilingual site? Maybe it's helpful if you can show the whole relevant templates...

Comment: In one template you have `{% placeholder "footer_info" or %}` and in the other `{% placeholder footer_info %}` which should be something different, also can't really tell from your postings how you wrapped your footer in django's `{% block .... %}`...

Comment: By "something" different, do you mean I need to get rid of the quotes in base.html? I tried that already. If that's not what you meant, then I assume you are saying it needs to have a different name like placeholder services_info. I tried that as well. Also, I didn't wrap the placeholder in a block tag.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15545/discussion-between-user14412-and-bernhard-vallant)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but did you publish the content added to footer_info on your home page? Also, I had to put quotes around "footer_info" and "home_cms_page". It is working for me.

Comment: @halfnibble, it is indeed an old post, and I don't even remember what I did with that project... but thanks so much for your help despite that the post is old :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the documentation:

> If you know the exact page you are referring to, it is a good idea to
>   use a reverse_id (a string used to uniquely name a page) rather than a
>   hard-coded numeric ID in your template. For example, you might have a
>   help page that you want to link to or display parts of on all pages.
>   To do this, you would first open the help page in the admin interface
>   and enter an ID (such as help) under the ‘Advanced’ tab of the form.
>   Then you could use that reverse_id with the appropriate templatetags:
>   {% show_placeholder "right-column" "help" %}

I added "index" in the advanced options of the index page, and added `{% show_placeholder "banner" "index" %}` in the base template. It all works.

Comment: There is a problem with show_placeholder. When you are using the front-end edition mode and publish from there, it doesn't publish the changes on the showed placeholder because it belong to another page.